Modern fantasy YA book with male protagonist who develops powers while visiting relatives for the summer
I read this book back in 2011, when I was around 10/11 myself. The protagonist was a male, around 16, along with the side character, female, also 16, and was poc and I vividly remember her wearing glasses. I remember the cover being a guy with a grey hood covering his face.
As for plot all I can remember is the guy goes to live with some relatives during the summer I believe. There’s a giant back garden and he starts to develop powers?
There’s a scene I distinctly remember where he uses his powers to float just outside of her window, and they talk in the dead of night about what had been going on. I think maybe he even had a sword or something??
The book was set in early 2000’s I believe. I’m desperate to find this book and it has been bugging me for years.  I love modern fantasy books and devastated I can’t find the one that got me hooked to the genre in the first place.

What does "he was poc" mean?

Person Of Color, I suspect. It's the new polite term for "Black" (that will probably be considered mildly offensive in another decade or so).

@FuzzyBoots part of the point of PoC is precisely that it isn't a polite term for "Black" but for "not White".

Ah, point accepted. I had only heard it used it reference to "black", not for, say, swarthy Italians, Mexican skin shades, or more Asian skin.
